# Xcode 6.1 quit unexpected due to the expired developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, iphone-developer-program, xcode6.1

Yesterday, I can run my project perfectly in xcode, but today when I open my project the xcode always quit unexpectedly. And my developer account expires today, and this app is built under my this expired account. I'm wondering is this the reason why the xcode quite unexpectedly?

```
Process:               Xcode [1352]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1 (6604)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6604000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       752282650
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1352]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-11-23 00:39:18.946 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        621A224C-863D-FF01-0409-8E03669992FE

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9C560417-B1A6-47C5-AA0D-7E5C5331F6FD

Time Awake Since Boot: 5500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1800 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): The index 9223372036854771711 is invalid
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of the crash log, its more likely just an invalid value somewhere.  That index is a 64 bit number that is very big (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFEFFF) and would be in invalid if it was somehow passed to an array or something.

Its best to run /Applications/Utilities/Console and see if there there are any errors that came from Xcode.  They may have more details.

Usually, if an account expires, associate apps are removed from the store and you can't access resources on the developer portal. I have not heard of Xcode stopping before.